How to Properly Refactor a Large Unity Script for Chunk Optimization Into Subclasses
I have a question regarding optimizing my map generation script in Unity. I recently completed an optimization script (MapOptimization) for new chunks, and I’m now considering splitting its functionality into two additional scripts to improve readability and modularity. The MapOptimization script currently has around 1,000 lines of code, and I’m contemplating creating two separate scripts: BorderOptimization and CornerOptimization, which would handle border and corner optimization tasks respectively.
Here's the structure I’m aiming for:

MapOptimization

BorderOptimization
CornerOptimization



See the structure here
My initial approach was to make BorderOptimization and CornerOptimization inherit from MapOptimization, as I need certain methods and variables from MapOptimization (e.g., a method that checks if there’s a neighboring block above or below a current block). However, I encountered an issue where calling an action delegate in BorderOptimization caused a NullReferenceException. This seems to be due to inheritance and the fact that all three scripts are attached as components to a single GameObject, which led to ProcessAllCubeDataOfNewChunk being called twice in the MapGenerator script. The delegate action in this process was null during the second iteration, causing the crash.
Although I attempted to resolve this with a Singleton pattern, it didn’t end up necessary as the ProcessAllCubeDataOfNewChunk and Start/Awake methods unexpectedly stopped being called twice. (I suspect it may relate to Unity’s execution order, though I’m still investigating.)
Despite resolving this specific duplication, querying the number of MapOptimization instances still shows 3 active instances, which I verified using:
int count = FindObjectsOfType<MyScript>(FindObjectsInactive.Include).Length;
Debug.Log("Total instances of MyScript (including inactive): " + count);

Additionally, for certain protected variables in MapOptimization to be accessible, I had to make them static. From my understanding, using static variables is generally discouraged in Unity, especially in game development, unless absolutely necessary.
Not inheriting from MapOptimization would complicate the structure, as it would require excessive qualifiers (e.g., mapOptimization.centerOfXNegativeNeighbourChunk) and make calling MapOptimization methods awkward. Keeping everything in a single script could work, but I’d prefer to avoid this if possible. Implementing an abstraction layer seems unfeasible given the context, and making MapOptimization abstract isn’t an option, as it contains [SerializedFields] and other variables and methods that require implementation.
Questions:

Is it feasible to have only one instance of MapGenerator when I want BorderOptimization and CornerOptimization to inherit from it, or am I fundamentally misunderstanding inheritance here?
In terms of clean code, is it valid to have multiple instances of MapOptimization if I can’t limit each child class (BorderOptimization, CornerOptimization) to a single instance, and would it be acceptable to make shared variables static in this context?
Performance-wise, whether I keep everything in one script or split it into multiple scripts, the performance impact I've checked through default & deep profiling seems similar.

Is there a better way to structure this so that I don’t have to keep both Border and Corner optimization functionalities in a single script? Any advice on how to solve this design puzzle is much appreciated.

"Scripts" are "classes". You can "split" classes using "partial" classes; which makes it easier to organize your code; and "bolt on" entire new functionality by just creating a new partial class with the same name; and that now "shares" everything. My main "game object" has 10+ partial classes: counters; geometry; events; event handlers; etc. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods

Why inherit though? Shouldn't the MapOptimization rather use and consume two modules BorderOptimization and CornerOptimization? These two shouldn't inherit from MapOptimization again ... (Composition Pattern)

In general of course such a question is hard to tell without knowing the exact code structure and functionality or the bigger picture of how it is used exactly...

Thank you for both approaches! It’s great to know that partial classes could work in this scenario. However, I’ve decided to keep the functionality in separate scripts and invoke the corresponding methods using actions.

After further investigation, I can confirm the following:

Single Instance of MapGenerator:
It is not feasible to maintain a single instance of MapGenerator while also having other child classes inherit from it. This is due to the inherent conflict that arises when multiple derived classes attempt to share or override behavior from the base class.

Avoiding Multiple Instances of MapGenerator:
Creating multiple instances of MapGenerator and using its fields as static shared data across child classes is not a good practice. This approach can lead to unnecessary complexity and maintenance challenges. Moreover, there's no practical reason to have more than one instance of MapGenerator since it wouldn't provide any performance benefit or improve functionality.

Avoiding Bidirectional Method Calls:
To prevent bidirectional dependencies between MapOptimization and BorderOptimization/CornerOptimization, I decided not to call the DoesNeighbourCubesOnYAxisExist method from MapOptimization within these scripts. Instead, I implemented the necessary logic independently in each script (While this approach fits me for now, I may revisit and refactor this solution in the future.)


In terms of implementation, I’ve opted to work through actions to manage calls to BorderOptimization and CornerOptimization. This approach appears to align somewhat with the Composition Pattern, although there is still more work to fit this pattern better.
Key Changes:

Passing Parameters Explicitly:
The Vector3 values that I originally intended to share between scripts are now being passed explicitly as parameters. This avoids shared state and improves the code's clarity and modularity.
Using Namespaces for Enums:
For the Border and Corner enums (which I omitted in my original question), I’ve introduced a new namespace, Game.MapOptimization. This ensures better organization and makes the enums accessible where needed without unnecessary coupling.

Bellow I'm sending how it looks like now (it isn't a full implementation).
namespace Game.MapOptimization ⬇️
internal enum Border
{
    Null,
    XPositive,
    XNegative,
    ZPositive,
    ZNegative
}

internal enum Corner
{
    Null,
    XPositive_ZPositive,
    XPositive_ZNegative,
    XNegative_ZPositive,
    XNegative_ZNegative
}

public class MapOptimization : MonoBehaviour
{
    internal Action<Border, Vector3, Vector3, Vector3, Vector3> onBorderOptimization;
    internal Action<Border, Vector3, Vector3, Vector3, Vector3> onCornerOptimization;

    private MapGenerator mapGenerator;

    void Awake()
    {
        mapGenerator = GetComponent<MapGenerator>();

        mapGenerator.onOptimizeChunk += OptimizeChunk;
    }

    private void OptimizeChunk()
    {
        Vector3 centerOfXNegativeNeighbourChunk = new Vector3(/* Corresponding Vector3 */);
        Vector3 centerOfXPositiveNeighbourChunk = new Vector3(/* Corresponding Vector3 */);
        Vector3 centerOfZNegativeNeighbourChunk = new Vector3(/* Corresponding Vector3 */);
        Vector3 centerOfZPositiveNeighbourChunk = new Vector3(/* Corresponding Vector3 */);

        onBorderOptimization(Border.Null, centerOfXNegativeNeighbourChunk,centerOfXPositiveNeighbourChunk, centerOfZNegativeNeighbourChunk, centerOfZPositiveNeighbourChunk);
        onCornerOptimization(Border.Null, centerOfXNegativeNeighbourChunk, centerOfXPositiveNeighbourChunk, centerOfZNegativeNeighbourChunk, centerOfZPositiveNeighbourChunk);
    }
    // Bunch of another code...
}

using Game.MapOptimization; ⬇️
public class BorderOptimization : MonoBehaviour
{
    MapOptimization mapOptimization;

    void Awake()
    {
        mapOptimization = GetComponent<MapOptimization>();
        
        mapOptimization.onBorderOptimization += OptimizeBorder;
    }

    private void OptimizeBorder(Border border, Vector3 centerOfXNegativeNeighbourChunk, Vector3 centerOfXPositiveNeighbourChunk, Vector3 centerOfZNegativeNeighbourChunk, Vector3 centerOfZPositiveNeighbourChunk)
    {
        // Process Border optimization...
    }
}

using Game.MapOptimization; ⬇️
public class CornerOptimization : MonoBehaviour
{
    MapOptimization mapOptimization;

    void Awake()
    {
        mapOptimization = GetComponent<MapOptimization>();
        
        mapOptimization.onCornerOptimization += OptimizeCorner;
    }

    private void OptimizeCorner(Border border, Vector3 centerOfXNegativeNeighbourChunk, Vector3 centerOfXPositiveNeighbourChunk, Vector3 centerOfZNegativeNeighbourChunk, Vector3 centerOfZPositiveNeighbourChunk)
    {
        // Process Corner optimization...
    }
}

